Is it possible to use Formik validation for forms which are created by react-admin library?
I am newbie, just started using the react-admin lib for one of my project. I could not find anywhere using formik with react-admin forms. So is it possible to use formik validation with react-admin forms.

React Admin uses react-hook-form (RHF) to manage its forms.
RHF supports several schema validation librairies out of the box, such as Yup, Zod or Joi.
Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a resolver for Formik.
You can still leverage Global Validation by passing your own validate function to the form, in which you should be able to validate form values using Formik.
Hope this helps!
